# Formula One (?) Hard Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence, formation-of-numbers

On a website I use to go, one of the writers gave this hard puzzle:

What are the meaning of those numbers given they are not Norwegian coordinates.

> 60.6604211,10.7210713

I have no clue how to solve it, the only thing I know it's a Formula One Sport website and this enigma was given on Max Verstappen Formula One Driver's topic, although I don't exclude it doesn't have a link with Max or Formula One.

I also know the comma and points are intended and on the right positions.

I thank the creator of this puzzle and give him his credit. It comes from [here](https://www.nextgen-forum.com/t8734p550-fmwc-topic-du-championnat-2020#1605496) and was posted by *tigo*.

Comment: The puzzle posted in the link said *Pour avoir Maxou vous devez trouver à quoi ceci correspond : 60.6604211,10.7210713* which google translates to "To have Maxou you must find out what this corresponds to: 60.6604211,10.7210713".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's pointing you to

> the Porsche R&D center at Weissach in Germany. Specifically, [the middle of the track there](https://goo.gl/maps/9w6KzaGfqo6v6Z386).

The code is a

> latitude-longitude pair in octal.

I figured this out by noticing that

> all the digits are less than eight.